# Codename One: How to display the contents of entire properties page

Tags: java, codenameone

I have a properties page that looks like this

```
property1=value1
property2=value2
property3=value3
property4=value4
```

And my plan is to be able to create a page in my app that will display these values and allow the user to change and save them.

The way that I thought I would do this is to create a method that will iterate through the file and populate a text control with the data.

I am using the 'propertyNames' function explained here https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/io/Properties.html

Unfortunately when I use this, all that is listed are the properties and not the values

Is there a way to show the entire contents of the properties file?

The other way I was thinking about doing it is to create a list of buttons that correspond to the keys - so one button for each key [with the key name as the button label] - and then when the user clicks on the button it displays the key value in an editable text box, and a save button that writes it back to the file.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`propertyNames` gives you all the keys, then you can retrieve the value of each get key using `getProperty`:

```
for(String key:props.propertyNames()){
  String value = props.getProperty(key);
  output += key+"="+value+"<br/>"; //however you output your stuff
}
```

After letting the user set new values, you can set them using `setProperty(key, newValue)`.